# Woo commerce add to cart not working after upgrading to php 7

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woo commerce in WordPress. Previously I am using php version 5.6 and everything is working fine. But server person upgrade to php version 7 and my woo commerce add to cart and some other things stopped working. When I click on add to cart its showing 'This page is not working'..... Even I have checkd my WordPress version is 5.1.1. Can anyone tell me any possible solution to resolve this issue. Thanks In advance.

Comment: Just make you debug mode on and check for issues in your debug log. May be you will get some information

Comment: What is the woocommerce version?

Answer (score 0):

Open wp-config.php file in your Wordpress installation and set wp_debug to true and then test it again.
To enable debugging you will need to add following in wp-config.php file

```
 define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
 define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
 define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
 define( 'WPS_DEBUG', true );
```

Then you can see your errors on screen. You can also find errors in  debug.log file in wp-content folder with errors.
Once you have knowledge about error/warnings then you can easily fix them by replacing depreciated functions with updated ones.

Here is a list of WooCommerce depreciated functions.
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/annotation-group-deprecated.html

Also make sure that you have latest Woo Commerce installed. Also note that there may be issues with your theme. May be you have outdated/depreciated code in your theme files which does not allow add to cart button to function properly.